# Using dataframe variable as argument in user-defined function

Tags: r, tidyverse, apply, gt

I would like to pass a variable in a dataframe to a function I've written. The function works, creating a png file with the gt package, when I manually type in a file name as the argument. However, when I attempt to pass a column in a dataframe that contains all the filenames needed to the function, it fails. I would like to create all the png files needed using the values in the column.

I can't share the real data. Fictional and simplified example follows.

Creating data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

# function makes png file from dataframe x 
makGt <- function(x) {
  select(x , fName) %>%
    gt(.) %>%
    gtsave(sprintf('fab4%s.png' , x[1,1]))
}

# example data
fName <- c('John' , 'Paul' , 'George' , 'Ringo')
byr <- c(1940 , 1942 , 1943 , 1940)
beatles <- data.frame(fName , byr) %>% arrange(fName)

# make individual files for each beatle
purrr::set_names(beatles %>% 
                   group_by(fName) %>%
                   group_split(), beatles$fName) %>%
  list2env(envir = globalenv())
```

Save a gt table in png format for George using the dataframe George

```
makGt(George) # creates png file for George using function
```

Futile attempts (two of many) to create png files using values from beatles$fName.

```
# attempts to use beatles fName variable in function makGt
makGt(sprintf('fab4%s' , beatles[1,1])) # results in error
sapply(beatles$fName , FUN = makGt) # error is same as above
```

Tidyverse-friendly code would be appreciated or using apply family. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the purpose of `makGt(sprintf('fab4%s' , beatles[1,1]))`? Based on your example, there should not be any object with a name of "fab4George"

Comment: My apology, that is an error from a previous version of my question. The argument should be "beatles[1,1]". I'll have to edit this tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `makGt` function, you'll need to `get()` the value of the object (which is in your case, get the dataframes created by `purrr` from `fName`).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

fName <- c('John' , 'Paul' , 'George' , 'Ringo')
byr <- c(1940 , 1942 , 1943 , 1940)
beatles <- data.frame(fName , byr) %>% arrange(fName)

purrr::set_names(beatles %>% 
                   group_by(fName) %>%
                   group_split(), beatles$fName) %>%
  list2env(envir = globalenv())

makGt <- function(x) {
  get(beatles$fName[x])[1] %>% 
    gt() %>% 
    gtsave(filename = sprintf('fab4%s.png' , 
                              beatles[x, 1]),
           path = getwd())
}

sapply(1:nrow(beatles), makGt)
```

This will save four `.png` files in your working directory with the name `fab4[fName].png`. I've included `fab4George.png` as an example output.

[image: fab4George]

Comment: Although this does produce the needed png files in this instance, it does not solve the problem. The gt tables need to come from the John, Paul, George and Ringo files. The file names need to come from beatles. In the actual work, some of the files I called John etc. have multiple rows, which is why the set_names block of code was run.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Hope I get your point this time, see my updated answer.

Comment: This is beautiful. Just so I understand the get() syntax:
`get(beatles$fName[1])` gets the file named George, not the first row of beatles.
In `get(beatles$fName[x])[1]` , [x] is the beatles row number, which progresses with sapply. In this latter statement [1] is not part of the file name but selects the first column of the file gotten with get().
For example, 
`get(beatles$fName[1])[1]` results in 
`# A tibble: 1 x 1
  fName 
  <chr> 
1 George` 
but `get(beatles$fName[1])` results in 
`# A tibble: 1 x 2
  fName    byr
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 George  1943` 
Output is from George.